# How to use a method that has no return type without making it public?

Tags: c#, oop, class, methods

I have a class that contains a method that has two parameters. I use properties to set the values for these parameters but I don't know how to pass them to the method. The class name is ZipLoad.

```
    private string user1;
    private string pass1;

    public string setUser
    {
        set { user1 = value ; }
    }
    public string setPass
    {
        set { pass1 = value; }
    }

    private void DOit(string uName, string pWord)
    {
      Do some stuff...
    }
```

I have this code to initialize it and all...

```
    ZipLoad myZipLoad = new ZipLoad();
    myZipLoad.setUser = "abc";  // can be anything !
    myZipLoad.setUser = "abc123";
```

What do I do next so I could use the method ?

Thank you.

Comment: `Don't know how to pass them to the method`
To which method? I don't understand the problem...
If you mean the `Doit` Method, then you don't need to pass them as parameters, you can access them directly.

Comment: Why do you declare the Method private if you want to be able to invoke it from outside the class?

Comment: Your question is *very* unclear. When are you trying to call the method, and what does this have to do with making public? And why are your properties so oddly named?

Comment: You should look at how properties [work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx) in .Net

Comment: I dont want the DOit method to be public. I want to set the username and password using the properties I created. I want to **supply** the vales that I **set** in these properties to the DOit method. Hope that clears things...

Comment: The method must be invoked at some point - where and when? If it´s not public then you can only invoke it within the class. I really don´t understand your intentions.

Comment: how about call DOit() in `public setUser {set{user1=value; DOit();}}`

Comment: Almost everyone here is telling me to make the DOit() method public. Can anyone tell me what's the point of having properties then ?

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
public ZipLoad(string uName,string pWord)
{
user1= uName;
pass1=pWord;
DOit(uName,pWord);
}
private string user1;
private string pass1;

private void DOit(string uName, string pWord)
{
  Do some stuff...
}
```

then you can call it by

```
ZipLoad myZipLoad = new ZipLoad("name","pw");
```

Comment: You forgot to pass the parameters, this will lead to an compiler error.

Comment: If i do it this way is it even necessary to have the strings user1, pass1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Not really clear were `DOit` method is, but if it is inside `ZipLoad` , you can just use fields, considering that properties has only `set`, for some reason.

So:

```
public class ZipLoad  {
 .... 
    private void DOit(string uName, string pWord)
    {
      Do some stuff...
    }

    //someone calls it 
    DOit(user1 , pass1);
 ....
}
```

But what I would do, is use property also internally, so define them like:

```
public string setUser
{        
    get {return user1}
}
public string setPass
{
    get{ returnpass1 ; }
}
```

and set values of the fields from ctor of the class, considering that these are properties 
that one must have in order to be able to use an object (at least as much as I understand from the code provided)

Answer (score 1):

If you have properties to set `user1` and `pass1` and your `DOit` method is set to `private`, you don't actually need to pass parameters to this method.

You can simply initialize your `ZipLoad` object:

```
ZipLoad myZipLoad = new ZipLoad();
myZipLoad.setUser = "abc";  // can be anything !
myZipLoad.setPass = "abc123";
```

as you already do, and then use properties value in `DOit` method. So the method can be redefined without parameters:

```
private void DOit()
{
    Do some stuff...
}
```

Comment: Oh, Now i get it. 
Thank you so very much. Now I understand what everyone was talking about. 
Thanks a million times.

Comment: Okay I have done as you said, Now how do I call the DOit() method ? !

Comment: @WaqasAli Because it is a private method, it can be invoked only by another method in your `ZipLoad` class. It could be a public method or another private method...

Comment: SO what you are saying is I have to create a public method to call a private method ?

Comment: It's not so clear what your method will do and when it must be called. But obviously if you need to call a method from another class you need a public method.

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting the values that are used in the method via properties then you don't need to pass them again to the method.

However if these variables are only ever going to be used in the method (and don't need to be stored in the ZipLoad class), then remove the properties and use the following:

```
myZipLoad.DOit("abc", "abc123");
```

You will have to make the `DOit` method public though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make you method `public`, and you dont need to pass username and password to method, you can simply use them in method.

```
public void DOit()
    {
       //you can reach your parameters from here...
    }
```

So you can use this like:

```
    ZipLoad myZipLoad = new ZipLoad();
    myZipLoad.setUser = "abc";  // can be anything !
    myZipLoad.setUser = "abc123";
    myZipLoad.DOit();
```

Answer (score 0):

The very basic principle using access modifier is that what level of permission you want to set. Using private means it is least access level. So, why do you design something private and want to use as public. Rather use public instead.

Refer to MSDN regarding accessibility levels:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ba0a1yw2(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a lot of confusion here. If I understand you correctly, you have two options, depending on what you would like to do.

**If you can change your method** signature, you can just do this:

```
private string user1;
private string pass1;

public string setUser
{
    set { user1 = value ; }
}
public string setPass
{
    set { pass1 = value; }
}

private void DOit() // Note: No parameters here!
{  
    // use setUser and setPass directly here, like:
    var user = setUser;
    Do some stuff...
}
```

**If you can not change your method signature**, and absolutely want to have the values passed as parameters for some reason (testing purposes perhaps, or some other reason?), maybe overloading is an option:

```
private string user1;
private string pass1;

public string setUser
{
    set { user1 = value ; }
}
public string setPass
{
    set { pass1 = value; }
}

// New method, just to call the other one:
private void DOit() 
{  
    // Just call the original method, with 
    // the properties as parameters:
    DOit(setUser, setPass);
}

// Your original method:
private void DOit(string uName, string pWord) 
{  
    Do some stuff...
}
```

Comment: Yes I can change the method signature but the method is still private. How do I call it then ?

Comment: I suppose I might have misunderstood your question. I thought the method was being called from somewhere else within the class (in which case it would be ok for it to be private). If you want to call the method from outside the class, it _must_ either be public (or possibly protected). Otherwise, you will have to call it from within the class - for instance from the `DOit()` method without parameters - but then _that_ method will have to be public. Then there is your last option, which is to call it from within the constructor (as in the answer provided Cloudsan Chen).